# MongoDB in M1 Mac: 'mongod' command doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, macos

I'm totally new to mongodb and has no knowledge about it at all.
So I just followed installation guides in the internet, but after installation 'mongod' command doesn't work and shows these lines...

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.029+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.030+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.032+09:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.032+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.034+09:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.034+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.034+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.034+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":45353,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"SUHONGui-MacBookAir.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.034+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.extfeatures"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.035+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.3","gitVersion":"657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.035+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.1.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.035+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.038+09:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.038+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.039+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T21:19:35.040+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

I've googled but couldn't find cases like above lines.
I'm using m1 mac and installed mongodb by typing

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@5.0
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

*"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path..."*

So... How about creating directory (where mongod process have right to write) or configure mongod to use some directory what exist already. :-)

Comment: same error, how to resolve it?

Comment: How to create a directory? Or how to change mongo.conf to point directory what already exists? Or... How to give RW rights to an existing directory?  All these are basic things that you already should know if you try to be DB admin.